# Users with both userTypes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've created an account with different values for both `userType=userName` and `userType=emailAddress`.

The documentation says this is allowed, but only the username is recognised during login.

Is this a bug in B2C or have I done something wrong? Thanks

Comment: How did you create those accounts?

Comment: Can you source: "The documentation says this is allowed"?

Answer (score 0):

A local account with an array of sign-in names of different sign-in types is allowed and you can log in to the local account with any sign-in name.

If you are creating built-in policies using the Azure AD B2C portal, then you must set the local account mode to "Username", in order to enable log in with any sign-in name.

(Setting this mode to "Username" changes the sign-in form. It doesn't limit logging in with only the "userName" sign-in type.)

Comment: Where do I set local account mode?

Comment: In the Azure AD B2C portal, open to the Identity Providers blade and select the "Local accounts" option.

Comment: Chris, making this change and attempting to sign-in an existing user, or creating a new user, both yield the same outcome: using the 'text' username works fine, but attempting to use the email-style username returns this error: "We don't recognize this user ID or password"

Answer (score 0):

You can login either with "user name or email address" of an user. But while you create the user in B2C, you should define the possible array of login names for that particular user.

```
      {"signInNames", new JArray
                        {
                            new JObject
                            {
                                {"value", "myTest@gmail.com"},
                                {"type", "emailAddress"}
                            },
                            new JObject
                            {
                                 {"value", "myTestUserName"},
                                 {"type", "userName"}
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Also, make sure you change the identity provider as "Local account Sign In" in the SignIn policy.